# bootstrap dropdown opening even after setting data-toggle=""

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to Disable the Bootstrap dropdown by setting `data-toggle=""` which is not working .The `ul` has `li`s ng-repeating on one array and if that array is empty i am setting `data-toggle=""` to not open the empty `li`.But this is not working it is still opening an empty list as given below.
[image]

Here is the template. you can see at `<button>` that the `data-toggle` is `empty` not `dropdown`.Still it opens the list.

```
       <div name="originFilter" id="originFilter" class="dropdown pa-leftFilter-dropdown-div open">

            <button id="selectBrand" class=" btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" disabledropdown="" disable="brands" data-toggle="" aria-expanded="true"> 
            <span id="selectedBrand" class="pa-text-wrapper-ellipsis pa-filter-selected-span ng-binding" ng-attr-title="{{selectedProperties.brand}}" title="LISTERMINT">BEBE</span><span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pa-filter-dropdown" role="menu" aria-labelledby="OriginDropDown">
                    <!-- ngRepeat: brand in brands -->
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-disabled true/false for making dropdown enable/disable